# How to test request timeout in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an asp.net core 3.1 application, which is providing a simple web service. In fact, it`s the template API application of Visual Studio including its WeatherForecastController.

The app that is consuming the web service is also developed by me and I'd like to initiate some behaviour tests on request timeouts, just to find out how my web service and how my consumer app are handling timeouts.
So I added a defined request timeout to the web.config of the webservice:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:00:20" processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" hostingModel="OutOfProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44382" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
  </system.webServer>
```

I also added a `ThreadSleep` of 300 seconds into my controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(300000);
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Très simple, nothing fancy.

Now, the challenge I am facing is that I would expect some sort of timeout exception to kick in once it passes the defined timeout limit. But this is not happening. Actually, the timeout settings in web.config seem to be completely ignored.
How can I test timeout settings in IISExpress? Am I missing a setting somewhere? Or is the timeout only ignored if I am attached with the debugger?

Comment: requestTimeout attribute doesn't apply to in-process hosting.. Can you try hosting with Kestrel and see if it works?

Comment: It is not InProcess, it`s OutOfProcess (see code snippet of web.config => ```hostingModel="OutOfProcess"```)

Comment: "the web.config of the webservice", then which path is that web.config? As it still contains `%LAUNCHER_PATH%`, not likely to be the right one.

Comment: Hi @Schadensbegrenzer, did you find any solution to this problem? tx!